# Problem With Print Report Directly To The Printer in Asp.net Core Web Api Using Devexpress

Tags: c#, printing, devexpress, webapi, devexpress-mvc

```
                var report = new InvoiceReport();
                report.DataSource=sourceOfReport;

                //Print Directly To Printer
                report.CreateDocumentAsync().Wait();
                var printTool = new PrintToolBase(report.PrintingSystem);
                //if PrinterName is Exist Then Send To it else Save as Pdf
                if (invoiceRequest.PrinterName!=null)
                    printTool.Print(invoiceRequest.PrinterName);
                else
                    printTool.Print();
                return Ok();
```

When I Send Printer Name Like :HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125-M126 PCLmS
I Got the Error Of :

> Settings to access printer '/HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125-M126 PCLmS' are not valid.

When I Send WithOut Name To Test I Get Error Of:

> No Printer is Installed

While there Are A printer Already installed And used To Print Pdf.
I Hope To Find Answer
Thanks.